# ActiveMQ Artemis web console through Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, console, activemq-artemis

How should the web server binding be configured for a Kubernetes Pod running ActiveMQ Artemis?

I have tried to replace the `localhost` with the K8s service, but the web server fails to bind. The web bind config is:

```xml
<web path="web">
   <binding uri="http://<K8s service name>:8161">
      <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
      <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
      <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </binding>
</web>
```

There is an Exception raised
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to eric-eo-cm-data-message-bus-art.liamtest.svc.cluster.local/10.108.83.108:8161

The Exception shows an IP and I do not know where that is coming from

Comment: Maybe I need to create a load balancer service and try to use that IP in some way

Comment: I think I need a broadcast,discovet & cluster config in broker.xml in order to run in Kubernetes

Comment: Clustering configuration has nothing to do with the embedded web server.

Comment: The hostname and IP address is coming from Kubernetes. If a valid value is not provided to the broker there's nothing the broker can do about it. This is really an environmental issue, not a broker issue.

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Yes.. Justin the service cannot be referenced in the Web binding of bootstrap.xml... I set host to 0.0.0.0:8161...so any machine client can access the Web service